# Taking screenshot in Shiny App in R not working

Tags: r, shiny, shinyscreenshot

I am trying to take a screenshot of my shiny app.

Everything is fine when I have just plots. But when I add a video, it just not working. I have the plots ok, but video area its just empty.

This is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinyscreenshot)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("go","Go"),
div(
  plotOutput("plot1"),
  tags$iframe(id = "video",width="560", height="315", src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/T1-k7VYwsHg", frameborder="0", allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture",
              allowfullscreen=NA),
  plotOutput("plot2")
)


)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

    ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,cyl)) + geom_point()

  })
  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({

    ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg,cyl)) + geom_point()

  })

observeEvent(input$go, {
  shinyscreenshot::screenshot(id = "video")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any help?

Is because the iframe?

How can I solve this??

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

[shinyscreenshot](https://github.com/daattali/shinyscreenshot#browser-support-and-limitations) is based on the html2canvas JavaScript library.

One of html2canvas limitations is mentioned [here](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation.html#limitations):

> All the images that the script uses need to reside under the [same
> origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) for it to be able to read them without the assistance of a
> [proxy](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/proxy/).

This restriction applies to the iframe unless you are willing to set up a proxy server.

However, videos in general seem to be [an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61492326/9841389).

You could try to screenshot another hidden html tag instead as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50273785/9841389).